# Grouping Repeated JSON Data using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

Please Help Me, I have a repeated JSON object like this :

```
[{
    "nip": "6080022A",
    "nama": "ASLAN PURNAMA",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": "Potensial",
    "semester1_2015": null
}, {
    "nip": "6080022A",
    "nama": "ASLAN PURNAMA",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": "Potensial"
}, {
    "nip": "6080048A",
    "nama": "NURHAYATI",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": "Potensial",
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": null
}, {
    "nip": "6080048A",
    "nama": "NURHAYATI",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": "Potensial",
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": null
}, {
    "nip": "6080048A",
    "nama": "NURHAYATI",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": "Potensial",
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": null
}, {
    "nip": "6080048A",
    "nama": "NURHAYATI",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": "Potensial",
    "semester1_2015": null
}, {
    "nip": "6080048A",
    "nama": "NURHAYATI",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": "Potensial"
}]
```

I would like to display the value using AngularJS, and the final result that I am expecting will be like this :

```
nip : 6080022A
nama : ASLAN PURNAMA
semester1_2012 : null
semester2_2012 : null
semester1_2013 : null
semester2_2013 : null
semester1_2014 : null
semester2_2014 : Potensial
semester1_2015 : Potensial

nip : 6080022A
nama : NURHAYATI
semester1_2012 : null
semester2_2012 : null
semester1_2013 : Potensial
semester2_2013 : Potensial
semester1_2014 : Potensial
semester2_2014 : Potensial
semester1_2015 : Potensial
```

I have tried to format the result using AngularJS Unique Filter but the result only filter the "nip" and "name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yXNp5fAUVdVLdgobB8aC?p=preview) (look at console). I used very cool library [linq.js](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/documentation?referringTitle=Home). Just process your initial array this way and use result array with ng-repeat, for example.

**Solution:**

```
$(function(){
   var array = [{
    "nip": "6080022A",
    "nama": "ASLAN PURNAMA",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": "Potensial",
    "semester1_2015": null
}, {
    "nip": "6080022A",
    "nama": "ASLAN PURNAMA",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": "Potensial"
}, {
    "nip": "6080048A",
    "nama": "NURHAYATI",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": "Potensial",
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": null
}, {
    "nip": "6080048A",
    "nama": "NURHAYATI",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": "Potensial",
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": null
}, {
    "nip": "6080048A",
    "nama": "NURHAYATI",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": "Potensial",
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": null
}, {
    "nip": "6080048A",
    "nama": "NURHAYATI",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": "Potensial",
    "semester1_2015": null
}, {
    "nip": "6080048A",
    "nama": "NURHAYATI",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": "Potensial"
}];            
   var res = Enumerable.From(array).GroupBy(function (x) { return x.nip + '&' + x.nama;} ).Select(function (x) { return { key: x.Key(), res:x.Aggregate(function(a,b){
     var res={};
     for(p in a)
        if(p!= 'nip' && p != 'nama')
            res[p]=a[p];
      for(p in b)
        if(p!= 'nip' && p != 'nama' && a[p]==null && b[p]!=null)
            res[p]=b[p];            

       return res;
   }) } }).ToArray().map(function(x){
     x.res.nip=x.key.split('&')[0];
     x.res.nama=x.key.split('&')[1];
     return x.res;
   });
   console.log(res);  
})
```

Comment: Oo my gosh ... It works, I've been searching for this solution since this morning, Thank You Slava